# Enum of tuples in Swift

Tags: swift

Is this possible to create a enum of Tuples in Swift?

I'd like to build something like:

```
enum ErrorCode: (Int, String) {
    case Generic_Error = (0, "Unknown")
    case DB_Error = (909, "Database")
}
```

But it doesn't compile... Is there a way to obtain a similar result?

Comment: Someone knows why this is not allowed in Swift?

Comment: you can provide your enum initializer for the enum which would get the tuple and initialize the case you need. Maybe this is what you need.. And then you can just call MyCustomEnum(tuple : (1,"myString")) and it would work. And inside the enum initializer you can use Swifts matching inside switch-case to do whatever miracle you need.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "similar". What I do is use a Struct with static constant properties:

```
struct Trouble {
    static let Generic_Error = (0, "Unknown")
    static let DB_Error = (909, "Database")
}
```

Now things like `Trouble.Generic_Error` are usable throughout your code.

Comment: I think this is best answer but Swift is more incompatible than Kotlin actually

Answer (score 60):

Swift enumerations cannot have Tuples as a raw value type.

Alternative approaches include storing the code and deriving a description from that:

```
enum ErrorCode: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Generic = 0
    case DB = 909

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Generic:
            return "Unknown"
        case .DB:
            return "Database"
        }
    }
}
```

...or storing associated values for code and description in the enumeration cases themselves:

```
enum Error {
    case Generic(Int, String)
    case DB(Int, String)
}
```

If you're just looking for constant values, @matt's suggestion of organizing them within a `struct` would work, too.

Comment: Printable is renamed to CustomStringConvertible

Comment: How would `Error` above be used exactly?

Comment: Oh yeah, you can put methods (and read-only vars) on the enum itself. So cool...  thanks!

Answer (score 50):

You can conform to `RawRepresentable` and use `(Int, String)` as the `Self.RawValue` associated type.

```
enum ErrorCode: RawRepresentable {
    case Generic_Error
    case DB_Error

    var rawValue: (Int, String) {
        switch self {
        case .Generic_Error: return (0, "Unknown")
        case .DB_Error: return (909, "Database")
        }
    }

    init?(rawValue: (Int, String)) {
        switch rawValue {
        case (0, "Unknown"): self = .Generic_Error
        case (909, "Database"): self = .DB_Error
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the the correct answer, it allows to use tuples, just like the question asked and not a struct (like the current correct answer)

Answer (score 20):

you can do such thing, maybe:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    case Generic_Error
    case DB_Error

    func values() -> (code: Int!, description: String?)! {
        switch self {
        case .Generic_Error:
            return (0, "Unknown")
        case .DB_Error:
            return (909, "Database")
        }
    }
}
```

and you can do such thing later:

```
let errorCode: ErrorCode = ErrorCode.Generic_Error;
if (errorCode.values().code == 0) {
    // do the business here...
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Create your `enum` and add a `var` of tuple type `(String, String)`.

```
enum SomeType {
    case type1
    case type2
    case type3

    var typeNameAndDescription: (name: String, description: String) {
       switch self {
       case .type1:
            return ("type1 name", "type1 description")
        case .type2:
            return ("type2 name", "type2 description")
        case .type3:
            return ("type3 name", "type3 description")
       }
    }
}
```

and later:

```
let myType = SomeType.type1
let typeName = myType.typeNameAndDescription.name
let typeDescription = myType.typeNameAndDescription.description
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution to keep the enum, was to create the get method for the rawValue var:

```
enum LoadingType {
  case poster
  case movie
  case refresh

  var rawValue: (file: String, anim: String) {
    get {
      switch self {
      case .movie:
        return ("poster_loading", "LoadingView")
      case .poster:
        return ("loading", "LoadingView")
      case .refresh:
        return ("loading", "RefreshView")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, you can even call each of your Tuple elements by a name:

```
self.type.rawValue.file
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I would change your code to something like this:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    case generic, db

    var message: String {
        switch self {
        case .generic:
            return "Unknown"
        case .db:
            return "Database"
        }
    }
    var code: Int {
        switch self {
        case .generic:
            return 0
        case .db:
            return 909
        }
    }
}
```

I feel this would make it much more easier to use like so:

```
let error = ErrorCode.generic
print("Error Code: \(error.code), Message: \(error.message)")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum ErrorCode {
    case Generic_Error
    case DB_Error

    public var code:Int{
        switch self {
        case .Generic_Error: return 0
        case .DB_Error: return 909
        }
    }

    public var name:String{
        switch self {
        case .Generic_Error: return "Unknown"
        case .DB_Error: return "Database"
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
let err:ErrorCode = .Generic_Error
print(err.code)   //0
print(err.name)   //Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in a similar situation.  Use an associated data enum, with default values (you can even name the values in the tuple if you like).  Then add a simple function that returns the tuple based on self.

```swift
    enum ErrorCode {
        case Generic_Error( code: Int = 0, desc: String = "Unknown")
        case DB_Error( code: Int = 909, desc: String = "Database")


        func getCodeDescription() -> (Int, String) {
            switch self {
                case let .Generic_Error(code, desc): return (code, desc)
                case let .DB_Error(code, desc):  return(code, desc)
            }
        }
    }
```

Later

```swift
    var errorCode: Int
    var errorDesc: String

    let myError: ErrorCode = .DB_Error() // let it take the default values 
    (errorCode, errorDesc) = myError.getCodeDescription()
```

Answer (score -4):

Create an Enumeration as Int.

For example:

https://github.com/rhodgkins/SwiftHTTPStatusCodes/blob/master/Sources/HTTPStatusCodes.swift

Comment: The link does show an example of a solution to this, but it is far from as simple as 'Create an Enumeration as Int'. It is basically equivalent to @mattt's first code example, but relies on NSHTTPURLResponse.localizedStringForStatusCode for the description rather than a switch over self. You should edit your answer with these details.