# Enum of booleans pairs

Tags: swift

I have a little problem with my enum. I try to declare this:

```
enum Test : (Bool, Bool) {
    case Both = (true, true)
    case None = (false, false)
}
```

I got this errors:

- Statement cannot begin with a closure expression
- Braced block of statements is an unused closure
- Expected identifier for type name
- Expected '(' in enum

Thanks for help :)

Comment: "It's wrong" - explain how it's wrong - does it create an error, does it not create the result you expect, etc.

Comment: Is this question about Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: You cannot have a tuple as the raw type of an enum, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387275/enum-of-tuples-in-swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be better off with `OptionSetType`:

```
struct MyOptions : OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int

    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }
    static let FirstOption = MyOptions(rawValue: 1)
    static let SecondOption = MyOptions(rawValue: 2)
    static let ThirdOption = MyOptions(rawValue: 4)
}

let opt1: MyOptions = []
let opt2: MyOptions = [.FirstOption, .ThirdOption]
```

`opt1` has all flags turned off. `opt2` has the first and third flags turned on. You can test if a flag is on by:

```
if opt2.contains(.FirstOption) {
    // true
}
```