# Is it possible to put a tuple in an enum with Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, tuples

If I have the following enum:

```
enum FruitTuple
{
    static let Apple = (shape:"round",colour:"red")
    static let Orange = (shape:"round",colour:"orange")
    static let Banana = (shape:"long",colour:"yellow")
}
```

Then I have the following function:

```
static func PrintFruit(fruit:FruitTuple)
{
    let shape:String = fruit.shape
    let colour:String = fruit.colour

    print("Fruit is \(shape) and \(colour)")
}
```

On the `fruit.shape` and `fruit.colour` I get the error:

`Value of type 'FruitTuple' has no member 'shape'`

Fair enough, so I alter the enum to have a type:

```
enum FruitTuple:(shape:String, colour:String)
{
    static let Apple = (shape:"round",colour:"red")
    static let Orange = (shape:"round",colour:"orange")
    static let Banana = (shape:"long",colour:"yellow")
}
```

But then on the enum declaration I get the error:

`Inheritance from non-named type '(shape: String, colour: String)'`

So, the question is: Is it even possible to have a tuple in an enum and be able to reference it's component parts in such a way? Am I just missing something fundamental here?

Comment: `FruitTuple.Apple` etc are just tuples, they are *not* enum values (you did not define any `case`s). `enum FruitTuple` only provides a "namespace" (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387275/enum-of-tuples-in-swift.

Comment: Cheers, that related question helps. The point about namespaces totally makes sense now too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @MartinR. Also, according to Apple docs, "enumeration cases can specify associated values of any type to be stored along with each different case value". If you want to keep using `enum`, you may need to do something like:

```
static func PrintFruit(fruit:FruitTuple.Apple)
{
    let shape:String = fruit.shape
    let colour:String = fruit.colour

    print("Fruit is \(shape) and \(colour)")
}
```

I'm not certain of what you want, but I guess using `typealias` could help achieve your goal.

```
typealias FruitTuple = (shape: String, colour: String)

enum Fruit
{
    static let apple = FruitTuple("round" , "red")
    static let orange = FruitTuple("round", "orange")
    static let banana = FruitTuple("long", "yellow")
}

func printFruit(fruitTuple: FruitTuple)
{
    let shape:String = fruitTuple.shape
    let colour:String = fruitTuple.colour
}
```

Comment: When you start using a type alias for a tuple, it's probably time for a struct

Comment: @Alexander Normally, if I have <=2 properties, I use tuple (w/ or w/o `typlealias`) to simplify the code with no need of constructors and customised equatable function. Could you pls point me out with the right direction why should I use struct in this case?

Comment: Well, you can't use these as Dictionary keys for one, because tuples can't conform to Hashable (or any protocols, for that matter). Also, `Fruit` can be any (`String`, `String`), tuple. My `typealias Person = (firstName: String, lastName: String)` tuple is the same type. I could say: `let p: Person = FruitTuple("round" , "red")`. Though I suppose some people are red, round and fruity, I don't think that's intended.